# What is the fastest way to read a file in disk in c++?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, readfile

I am writing a program to check whether a file is PE file or not. For that, I need to read only the file headers of files(which I guess do not occupy more than first 1024 bytes of a file).

I tried using creatfile() + readfile() combination which turns out be slower because I am iterating through all the files in system drive. It is taking 15-20 minutes just to iterate through them.

Can you please tell some alternate approach to open and read the files to make it faster?

Note : Please note that **I do NOT need to read the file in whole**. I just need to read the initial part of the file -- DOS header, PE header etc which I guess do not occupy more than first 512 bytes of the file.

Here is my code :

```
bool IsPEFile(const String filePath)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
const DWORD CHUNK_SIZE = 2048;
BYTE szBuffer[CHUNK_SIZE] = {0};
LONGLONG size;
LARGE_INTEGER li = {0};
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{       
    if(GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &li) && li.QuadPart > 0)
    {
        size = li.QuadPart;
        ReadFile(hFile, szBuffer, CHUNK_SIZE, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
        if(dwBytesRead > 0 && (WORDPTR(szBuffer[0]) == ('M' << 8) + 'Z' || WORDPTR(szBuffer[0]) == ('Z' << 8) + 'M'))
        {
            LONGLONG ne_pe_header = DWORDPTR(szBuffer[0x3c]);
            WORD signature = 0;
            if(ne_pe_header <= dwBytesRead-2) 
            {
                signature = WORDPTR(szBuffer[ne_pe_header]);
            }
            else if (ne_pe_header < size )
            {
                SetFilePointer(hFile, ne_pe_header, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
                ReadFile(hFile, &signature, sizeof(signature), &dwBytesRead, NULL);
                if (dwBytesRead != sizeof(signature))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(signature == 0x4550) // PE file
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using C's `FILE` or C++ `fstream` and see if they are fast enough?

Comment: Why is your question tagged [tag:c] if your question is about C++? That makes no sense, son.

Comment: What are creatfile and readfile?

Comment: It's hard to say what's fastest - it may depend on all sorts of things such as the drive's firmware, seek time, the OS version etc..  I doubt there'll be much difference between them, but if I were you and ***really*** cared, I'd benchmark to compare an `ifstream`  with memory mapping (boost has an implementation if you don't want to code it yourself).

Comment: <offtop>Are you creating virus? ))</offtop>

Comment: Assuming you got the SSD (which solves the first bottleneck), you probably want to check the cluster size of the file system and issue non-cached reads for one whole cluster.

Comment: Keeping file handles open for longer than necessary surely won't speed things up. Your code leaks a file handle for **every** PE module, and for some files that aren't.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're hitting the inherent limitations of mechanical hard disk drives. You didn't mention whether you're using a HDD or a solid-state disk, but I assume a HDD given that your file accesses are slow.

HDDs can read data at about 100 MB/s sequentially, but seek time is a bit over 10 ms. This means that if you seek to a certain location (10 ms), you might as well read a megabyte of data (another 10 ms). This also means that you can access only less than 100 files per second.

So, in your case it doesn't matter much whether you're reading the first 512 bytes of a file or the first hundred kilobytes of a file.

Hardware is cheap, programmer time is expensive. Your best bet is to purchase a solid-state disk drive if your file accesses are too slow. I predict that eventually all computers will have solid-state disk drives.

Note: if the bottleneck is the HDD, there is nothing you can do about it other than to replace the HDD with better technology. Practically all file access mechanisms are equally slow. The only thing you can do about it is to read only the initial part of a file if the file is really really large such as multiple megabytes. But based on your code example you're already doing that.

Comment: The problem indeed is hardware. The problem described here is the lack of "random IOPS" (I/O operations per second) from a mechanical HDD.

Answer (score -1):

For faster file IO, you need to use `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` APIs of Win32.
If you want to speed up, you can use file buffering and make file non-blocking by using overlapped IO or IOCP.

See this example for help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And I think that `FILE` and `fstream` of C and C++ respectively are not faster than Win32.

Comment: Pretty sure CreateFile / ReadFile are what the OP is calling "too slow".

Comment: I have mentioned overlapped or IOCP.

Comment: _"I think that FILE and fstream of C and C++ respectively are not faster than Win32"_ - in fact, C++ file streams likely just use C streams, which most certainly are implemented using the Win32 file API.